# XSL transformation using xsl:for-each not giving proper output

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to modify the XML using `<xsl:for-each>` and it is giving me weird results, it's getting overridden all the time.

Version 1.0

Is there any way we can achieve it ?

Input:

```
 <Test>
   <Tests>
      <Tests1 name="value1" value = "10" />
      <Tests1 name="value2" value = "20" />
   </Tests>
   <Tests>
      <Tests1 name="value1" value = "30" />
     <Tests1 name="value2" value = "40" />
   </Tests>
</Test>
```

Expected result

```
<Test value1Sum = "40" value2Sum="60">
</Test>
```

Comment: What is the XSLT you're using to do this transform? And what version is it?

Comment: Please edit your question and add (1) your XSLT and (2) the expected output.

Comment: xslt version 1.0

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: I find it really hard to see how one would use an `xsl:for-each` in this transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of reporting the `sum()` of all the `@value` for the various `@name`. Using `xsl:key` for `@name` you can use `xsl:for-each` and for each of the distinct names, generate an attribute that appends "Sum" to the name and the `sum()` of all the `@value` for that `@name` selected with `key()` and then traversing from `@name` to it's `@value` via XPath.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="names" match="*[@value]/@name" use="."/>

    <xsl:template match="Test">
        <Test>
            <xsl:for-each select="//@name[generate-id() = generate-id(key('names', .)[1])]">
                <xsl:attribute name="{concat(.,'Sum')}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('names', .)/parent::*/@value)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Test>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```